# Tag Manager No Longer Working - Android Studio 2.2.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logging, firebase

I have recently upgraded to Android Studio 2.2.2 and also migrated to the new Firebase SDK located [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android). Since then, I noticed that I can no longer view Logging. In the code below, I am simply checking to see if a user is logged in / authenticated, yet my log is not showing any activity (see screenshot):

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("OnCreate_TRIGGERED", "OnCreate HAS BEEN TRIGGERED");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);

    final DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseUtil.FIREBASE.child("Users");

    Thread thread=  new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(3000);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){
            }
            mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    if (user != null) {
                        // User is signed in
                        Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    } else {
                        // User is signed out
                        Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    }

                }
            };
       }
    };
    thread.start();
    }

  }
```

In my code, I set basic logs to determine the authentication status of the user. However, when I search for the tag in the Android Monitor, I see that for some reason the Tag Manager is not working. I have previously used the Tag Manager with no issues, therefore I am concerned that my update to Android Studio 2.2.2 caused the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your listener to be effective, it [must be registered](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)).  There is also no need for the worker thread processing.  Remove the thread and replace it with this:

```
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }

        }
    };

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
```

Comment: Much appreciated, however this resolves a Firebase issue. If you look at the image I have included, Android Studio is not recognizing tagging. I could be wrong, but just want to make sure that it isn't a Studio-wide setting that I need to adjust

Comment: On the left border of the Android Monitor window, click on the icon that looks like a gear/cog.  In the dialog that appears, click on "Show tag" if it is not already checked.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot and mark as correct if works

Comment: After looking again at your logcat output, I can see that the tags are in the headers, for example, "D/Hylog" is a tag.  If you are expecting to see "TAG" and are not, it's because you are not generating any logs with that tag.

Comment: I use Log.d("TAG"), so how is that so? I did that previously and it worked fine.

Comment: I can only suggest you experiment:  unclick "Regex", retype various search strings to see what results.  Also try clearing the search filter and using Ctrl-F to search the body of the Android Monitor window.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't add the last line that you listed, it looks like that last line is part of the new Firebase SDK?